# HairNet addon moves other hair systems on same emitter mesh

Tags: particles, hair

I've been scouring the web for any documentation on this for hours and can't seem to find any comprehensive info. I have a scalp which has a hair system on it created from curves using the HairNet add on. When on it's own it works as expected, but as soon as I select another curve to create a new hair system on the same object, the first system's guides get all wonky. This exact result also happens when I disconnect and reconnect my hair system. Does anyone have any ideas what causes this?

You can see the difference of before adding a new system and after.
[image: Original hair system created from curves using Hairnet]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This bug happens since Blender 2.9 and HairNet 0.6.2 were released. The hair particles of one of the existing hair particle systems move down along the z-axis for some reason when another hair particle system is added by HairNet.

You can pull the hair particles up again in comb mode but a better workaround is to disable all existing hair particle systems in the viewport before you add another hair particle system with the addon. After the new one is added you can enable them again.

[image: disabled particle systems]